# I am preparing a letter for the board of directors

Tags: grammar

Where can I find a website that will teach me how to prepare an informing letter for the board of directors regarding starting of a construction?

Comment: Probably your question will go off-topic unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

This site teaches you how to write a letter to the board of directors.

https://bizfluent.com/how-8537211-write-formal-letter-board-directors.html

and

https://www.reference.com/education/write-letter-board-directors-2c100ad3543b80d5